Как изменить цвет черной полосы в нижней части экрана приложения MAUI
Я разрабатываю приложение на maui уже кучу файлов облазил, но я не могу найти как изменить цвет в области панели навигации. Помогите пожалуйста, я не понимаю как это пофиксить.


Давайте начнём с того, а что это за платформа? iOS?

Нет, это андроид
